# The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm following up with this [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-dart-the-complete-flutter-app-development-course/) course but I face this error when I run the app on Android emulater on windows machine it shows the button on the whole screen

the app simple I'm just trying to get data from the user to store it in s file then print it in the console

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Qo6.png)

**Expected result**

[image]

My code:-

main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


void main() async{

  var data = await readData();
  if(data != null){
    print(data);
  }

  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        title: "IO",
        home: Home(),
      )
  );
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  var _enterDataField = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Read/Write"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(13.4),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: ListTile(
          title: TextField(
            controller: _enterDataField,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Input Something"
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: FlatButton(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            onPressed: (){
              print("Flat button");
              writeData(_enterDataField.text);
            },
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Save Data"),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.5)),
                Text("Save data goes all"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path; // /home/directory/
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File("$path/data.txt"); // /home/directory/data.txt
}

Future<File> writeData(String message) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.writeAsString("$message");
}

Future<String> readData() async{
  try{
    final file = await _localFile;
    String data = await file.readAsString();
    return data;
  }catch(e){
    return "Nothing has been saved yet!";
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
```

Error during run:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 4904): Nothing has been saved yet!
I/Choreographer( 4904): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 4904): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7085900: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe70839b0)
I/flutter ( 4904): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4904): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 4904): not implemented
I/flutter ( 4904): 'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart': Failed assertion: line 977 pos 12: 'false'
I/flutter ( 4904): 
I/flutter ( 4904): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 4904): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 4904): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 4904):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 4904): 
I/flutter ( 4904): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4904): #2      _RenderDecoration.computeDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:977:12)
I/flutter ( 4904): #3      RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:50)
I/flutter ( 4904): #4      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:281:23)
I/flutter ( 4904): #5      RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:22)
I/flutter ( 4904): #6      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:97:20)
I/flutter ( 4904): #7      RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:50)
I/flutter ( 4904): #8      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:281:23)
I/flutter ( 4904): #9      RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:22)
I/flutter ( 4904): #10     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:97:20)
I/flutter ( 4904): #11     RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:50)
I/flutter ( 4904): #12     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:281:23)
I/flutter ( 4904): #13     RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:22)
I/flutter ( 4904): #14     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.computeDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:97:20)
I/flutter ( 4904): #15     RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:50)
I/flutter ( 4904): #16     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:281:23)
I/flutter ( 4904): #17     RenderBox.getDistanceToActualBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1672:22)
I/flutter ( 4904): #18     RenderBox.getDistanceToBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1655:27)
I/flutter ( 4904): #19     _RenderListTile._boxBaseline (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:886:16)
I/flutter ( 4904): #20     _RenderListTile.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:945:32)
I/flutter ( 4904): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #22     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter ( 4904): #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #24     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #26     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #28     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #30     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:385:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #32     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter ( 4904): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #34     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter ( 4904): #35     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:339:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #36     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #37     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter ( 4904): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #42     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1203:11)
I/flutter ( 4904): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #46     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #50     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #52     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #56     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #59     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2900:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #61     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 4904): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #63     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #65     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #67     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #69     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #71     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #73     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #75     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:147:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #76     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1509:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #77     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:768:18)
I/flutter ( 4904): #78     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:281:19)
I/flutter ( 4904): #79     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:686:13)
I/flutter ( 4904): #80     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
I/flutter ( 4904): #81     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 4904): #82     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 4904): #83     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
I/flutter ( 4904): #85     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 4904): #86     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 4904): #87     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter ( 4904): (elided 3 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 4904): 
I/flutter ( 4904): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 4904):   _RenderListTile#c955b relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):   creator: _ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 4904):   RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← InkWell ← ListTile ← Align ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 4904):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 4904):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=352.6, 0.0<=h<=668.1)
I/flutter ( 4904):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 4904): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 4904):   RenderSemanticsAnnotations#30cbc relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):     RenderIgnorePointer#d2ac5 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):       RenderPointerListener#95c88 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):         _RenderDecoration#d39f5 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):           RenderRepaintBoundary#7e8a4 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):           RenderTransform#6a1d0 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):           RenderConstrainedBox#bd9be relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):           RenderCustomPaint#862dd NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):   RenderSemanticsAnnotations#103e3 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):     _RenderInputPadding#ab3b4 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):       RenderConstrainedBox#39a4f relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):         RenderPhysicalShape#32f8b relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904):           RenderCustomPaint#5950d relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4904): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#c955b relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#a1895 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#9585a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#867ef relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 4904): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 314 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
D/        ( 4904): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xce8870c0, tid 4923
D/EGL_emulation( 4904): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe569c960: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe447f500)
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use this.

```
Widget _myWidget() {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Write Something")),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Text("Save Data"),
            Spacer(),
            Text("Save Data goes here"),
          ],),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the code to be like this in order to work

```
FlatButton(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: (){
                print("Flat button ${_enterDataField.text}");
                writeData(_enterDataField.text.toString());
              },
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Save Data"),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.5)),
                  FutureBuilder(
                    future: readData(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> data){
                      if(data.hasData != null){
                        return Text(
                          data.data.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                          ),
                        );
                      }else{
                        return Text("No data has been saved");
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

when I wrap the text field in sizedBox and give height and width the the error has gone. Error is due to when we take the textfield in a Row.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).